# In bazel, how do I get the directory a generated file is in?

Tags: bazel

I have a rule, `//foo/bar/baz:thing`. This generates some files, including `thing.h`. These go... somewhere; bazel chooses where. It's just a genrule, so there's not C library magic.

I then have a `cc_binary` rule. It's in a different package and wants to refer to `thing.h`. So, I do this:

```
cc_binary(
    name="consumer",
    srcs=[
        ...some sources...
        "//foo/bar/baz:thing.h"
    ],
    deps=["//foo/bar/baz:thing"]
)
```

This fails, because while the appropriate directory did get added to the include path for the program to find `foo/bar/baz/thing.h`, the program's actually doing `#include "thing.h"`. So I need to add the *directory containing* `thing.h` to the include path. (Changing the program isn't an option.)

How? Simply doing `copts=["-I$(location //for/bar/baz:thing.h)"]` won't work, because that'll return the location of the file *itself*, and not the directory that the file is *in*. Doing `copts=["-I$$(dirname ...)"]` doesn't work because C++ compiler command lines don't go through the shell. And I can't use `$(RULEDIR)` because `thing.h` was generated in a different package...

Comment: Is `//foo/bar/baz:BUILD.bazel` editable or a third party dependency?

Comment: I am asking mostly because of this statement "(Changing the program isn't an option.)" which seems to suggest that it might be, and it changes the potential solutions you might have available to you.

Comment: I'm making the build files for a third party source tree. Patching the program itself is undesirable because that will make importing new upstream versions more difficult. (Plus I resent having to change the source just to make the build system happy.)

Answer (score 1):

Specify the header in `//foo/bar/baz:thing` and use [`includes`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_library.includes), like this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "thing",
    hdrs = ["thing.h"],
    includes = ["."],
)
```

Then you just need `//foo/bar/baz:thing` in `deps` for `consumer` (like you already have) and it'll all work.

In general, the Bazel C/C++ rules are designed for the files being compiled (whether they're source files or generated) to be included in exactly 1 `cc_*` rule in the same package. If you find yourself trying anything else, keep in mind that the C/C++ rules aren't designed for it and might get in the way.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how the source is laid out --- there's source in one directory which is intended to be used directly by a library in another directory (combined with a configuration .h file).

Comment: The Bazel C/C++ rules are set up to put a cc_library in the BUILD file which generates the configuration .h file. You don't need to change the source layout to do that.

Comment: The configuration file is in a different package to the source code.